# How to include/preappend copyrightFile in a DOJO layer?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using DOJO 1.10, I need to include/preappend  some copyright information inside the file for a layer (the concatenated file).

I am following the instruction from the [doc](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/profiles.html) both with local and absolute path to the copyright  file (.txt file).

With no success.

Notes:
Also the docs clearly say thatthe default Dojo copyright notice will be
used instead if copyrightFile property is not provided, but neither this text information is never included in my layers.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var profile = function() {
    return {
        basePath: "../",
        releaseDir: "dist",
        releaseName: "build",
        optimize: "closure",
        action: "release",
        layerOptimize: "closure",
        copyTests: !1,
        stripConsole: "all",
        version: "ntv-0.0.0",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        mini: !0,
        staticHasFeatures: {
            "dojo-trace-api": !1,
            "dojo-log-api": !1,
            "dojo-publish-privates": !1,
            "dojo-sync-loader": !1,
            "dojo-xhr-factory": !1,
            "dojo-test-sniff": !1
        },
        resourceTags: {
            amd: function(t) {
                return /\.js$/.test(t)
            },
            ignore: function(t) {
                return /\.js.map$/.test(t)
            },
            miniExclude: function(t) {
                return /\.js.map$/.test(t)
            }
        },
        packages: [{
            name: "dojo",
            location: "dojo"
        }, {
            name: "test",
            location: "test"
        }],
        layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                include: ["dojo/dojo"],
                customBase: true,
                boot: false
            },
            "test/c": {
                include: ["test/c/c"],
                customBase: true,
                boot: false,
            copyrightFile: 'C:\copyright.txt'
            },
            "test/b": {
                include: ["test/b/b"],
                customBase: true,
                boot: false,
            copyrightFile: 'C:\copyright.txt'
            },
            "test/a": {
                include: ["test/a/a"],
                customBase: true,
                boot: false,
            copyrightFile: 'C:\copyright.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear this behavior changed and was perhaps not well-documented for 1.7+ build profiles.  It's [mentioned](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/transforms/writeAmd.html?highlight=copyright) but kind of hard to find.

When using the new profile format (e.g. with a `layers` hash instead of array), the property is named `copyright` instead of `copyrightFile`, and it seems to default to nothing.

For example, to add the default Dojo copyright message to a layer, you'd set `copyright: 'util/build/copyright.txt'` (assuming `util` is directly under `basePath`).

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help on this. I wondering if you could also have a quick look at this related question..I really appreciate your time on this. Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584758/copyonly-does-not-work-in-profile

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary work around to this problem, as I am using Google Closure compiler I can use `@preserve` or `@license` in order to preserve some annotation in my JavaScript.

Here an example of what I am using in my source code. Nether than less, I still very interested to use `copyrightFile` from DOJO instead.

```
/**
 * @preserve Copyright 2009 SomeThirdParty.
 * Here is the full license text and copyright
 * notice for this file. Note that the notice can span several
 * lines and is only terminated by the closing star and slash:
 */
```

Related:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler